# How do I know mapped port of host from docker container?

Tags: linux, port, containers, docker

I have a docker container running where I a have mapped 8090 port of host to 8080 port of docker container (running a tomcat server). Is there any way by which I can get the mapped port information from container?

i.e. is there any way by which I can get to know about 8090:8080 mapping from container?

Comment: Seems like a bad idea. The whole point is for containers to be unaware of their execution context. That being said, I'm starting to experiment with service discovery, built into my application (systems like: consul, etcd, zookeeper, etc) which means the container could simply look itself up at run-time.

Comment: Thanks Mark I got your point. I need this information in a code segment of web application.

Answer (score 0):

When you [link containers, docker sets environment variables](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/#container-linking) which you can use inside one docker to tell how you can communicate with another docker. You can manually do something similar to let your docker know about the host's mapping:

```
export HOST_8080=8090
docker run -p $HOST_8080:8080 -e "HOST_8080=$HOST_8080" --name my_docker_name my_docker_image /bin/bash -c export
```

**explanation**:

`export HOST_8080=8090` defines an environment variable on your host (so you won't have to write the "8090" thing twice).

`-p $HOST_8080:8080` maps the 8090 port on the host to 8080 on the docker.

`-e "HOST_8080=$HOST_8080"` defines an [environment variable](https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#env-environment-variables) inside the docker, which is called HOST_8080, with value 8090.

`/bin/bash -c export` just prints the environment variables so you can see this is actually working. Replace this with your docker's CMD.

Comment: Thanks Ofri, Yes, I have used the same idea for forwarding the port as well IP address of host machine to the container by setting env variables.

Comment: Pity this is not possible yet, without a hack. 
 This may fix it in the future. https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/26331