# Etcd alternative that runs only on one machine?

Tags: distributed

I want to share, store and monitor some date between different servers.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32444612/how-to-get-the-mapped-port-on-host-from-a-docker-container]) is what I want to do. I found all I need is to have a place that the manager write commands to, and the workers read commands and do it. The workers should also register themselves there so I get some information. TTL is also needed, so I can tell if a worker stopped.

Etcd seems good but I don't need that reliability. And it is too over weighted for me. Is there an similar thing runs on a single machine? It's better to have low latency, so when the manager write a command, the worker receive it quickly.